# Do websites that re-sell preowned game discs face any copyright problems?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I read on a game CD that

> Unauthorised copying, adaptation, rental, lending, distribution, re-sale, etc. are prohibited

So how can websites like Gamestop legally re-sell preowned game discs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't get hung up on unauthorized resale. That only prohibits unauthorized resale. Authorized resale is ok.

From http://www.justice.gov/usam/criminal-resource-manual-1854-copyright-infringement-first-sale-doctrine:

> The first sale doctrine, codified at 17 U.S.C. § 109, provides that an
>   **individual who knowingly purchases a copy of a copyrighted work from
>   the copyright holder receives the right to sell**, display or otherwise
>   dispose of that particular copy, notwithstanding the interests of the
>   copyright owner. The right to distribute ends, however, once the owner
>   has sold that particular copy. See 17 U.S.C. § 109(a) & (c). Since the
>   first sale doctrine never protects a defendant who makes unauthorized
>   reproductions of a copyrighted work, the first sale doctrine cannot be
>   a successful defense in cases that allege infringing reproduction.